# DOM Manipulation vs Templating

Tags: javascript, performance, templates, dom, cordova

So I'm in the midst of a performance overhaul of a little HTML5 phonegap application I'm developing and I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle a semi-frequently updating `<ul>` element.

I'm currently using `DocumentFragments` for the initial mass injection of the db data and then jQuery's `prepend()` and `remove()` functions for management.

I've been looking at templates, [EJS](https://ejs.co) in particular, and I was wondering if I would get any performance boosts if I implemented it.

If so why? And if not also why?

Also any other tips for performant DOM manipulation are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think templates will give you performance boost (if you don't cache your template).

You have to process the data to generate html anyway.

Templates just makes generation of html easier, readable and reusable.

I could add little more-

1. Cache your template will boost performance [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/dom-select-vs-cache/2)
2. Reduce reflow (minimize regenartion of render tree)
3. Don't add styles directly use css class
4. Endless so called best practice

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of js template engines.

**BUT**, you need to take a lot of care on render html through a javascript code.

The main problem is that search engines don't see them.

The second problem is the performance, the best way to render html is on server-side [as twitter does](https://blog.twitter.com/2012/improving-performance-twittercom), because you need to consider that your website speedy depends upon the client environment, and all your users don't have the best machine to see it.

Then, I believe that the best web site's architecture to follow is the twitter.com. They implemented a mix of server-side render and  client-side render. The first request is rendered by server-side and the next ones are redered by javascript through ajax requests.